# Removing everything after a word that is present in multiline or with in the same line

Tags: python-3.x, regex

There are multiple mails other than the format I have mentioned here. All I want to do is, if a line has 'regards' in it I want to remove the text that is present in the line as well as the lines that are after it.Example, the email data is like this:

```
1.
regards,
xyz.

2.
best regards,
abc
def
ghi
jkl

3.
thanks and regards,
mno
```

Tried the following ways:

```
#one way  
clean_text = re.sub('\n.*regards.*$\n.*\n.*\n.*','',clean_text)
#other way
clean_text_lst = re.split('\n.*regards.*',clean_text)
clean_text = clean_text_lst[0]#getting only the body of the email, removing the unnecessary details
```

If there is any regular expression that can parse through the text till the end of the string  without bothering about new lines('\n') it would be great.

Comment: What is the expected output? If it's not simply `1.` how do we know when to stop removing?

Comment: Are you looking for `re.sub(r'.*[Rr]egards,.*(?:\n\s*\S.*)*', '')`?

Comment: I was looking for this re.sub(r'\n.*regards.*(?:\n\s*\S.*)*',''). Thank you for the help

Comment: Try `^(?:(?!.*regards)\S.*\r?\n)*.*\bregards\b.*(?:\r?\n\S.*)*`  https://regex101.com/r/cPhj2F/1

Answer (score 0):

**regex:** `.*regards[^\n]+\n[^\n]+`

```
import re

sample = """
1.
regards,
xyz.

2.
best regards,
abc
def
ghi
jkl

3.
thanks and regards,
mno
"""

print(re.sub(r".*regards[^\n]+\n[^\n]+", "", sample))
```

**Output:**

```
1.


2.

def
ghi
jkl

3.
```

https://regex101.com/r/3d7DMz/2

Comment: I wanted to just get the numbers(1.,2.,3.), I have got the answer that works in my case. Anyways thanks for the help. Ans:"re.sub(r'\n.*regards.*(?:\n\s*\S.*)*','')". It's my fault that I was not able to explain the question properly..my bad

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove the "regards" line and all non-empty lines immediately after it, try

```
clean_text = re.sub(r'.*[Rr]egards,.*(?:\n\s*\S.*)*', '', clean_text)
```

The regex matches zero or more repetitions of newline, (any whitespace as long as followed by) any non-whitespace character, followed by anything (except newline), i.e. all lines which are not empty after the "regards" line.

Maybe put `'\n'` as the replacement instead of `''` to preserve another empty line where you removed stuff; (like much else in your question) it's not exactly clear what result you are looking for.